# Is it possible to have binding-less blocks?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to pass a block to a method, and make sure that the block has no binding on its own, so that it can only be executed in the context of another instance (using `{class/module/instance}_eval`) and not by simply sending `:call`?

Here is a motivating example

```
module M
  class File
  end  
end  
M.module_eval "File"      # => M::File
M.module_eval do File end # => File
```

I would like the last line above to return the `M::File` class instead of `::File`.

Another thing to have in mind is that in my concrete application the module `M` is created dynamically (inside a method call), as opposed to statically (in a Ruby file, like above). This is how it actually works:

```
def create_module(name, &block)
  mod = Module.new
  Object.send :const_set name, mod
  mod.module_eval &block
end

create_module :M do
  file_cls = Class.new
  M.send :const_set, :File, file_cls
  File # => ::File (and I would like M::File)
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: `module M; module_eval do File end; end` is probably *not* what you want here? But I think I need to see some other use case to understand you better and rule out that syntax.

Comment: Not exactly.  I actually have a method that takes a block, and that method first creates the a module (`M` in this example) and then calls `module_eval` on it, passing the given block.

Comment: You seem to be confusing namespaces with bindings. A binding is a state of variable-value pairs like `x` is `3`, etc. What you seem to be wanting is not binding but namespace to be set to a particular state.

Comment: What is wrong with `M.module_eval "File"`? Or why doesn't `M::File` work? What conditions do you put on the expected answer?

Comment: I'd like to see how you are creating the module, and what handle you have to it - e.g `m = Module.new` ?

Comment: Good point about namespaces vs bindings.  In this example with how  `File` is resolved, it is really about namespaces, but in general I would also like the block I pass to `create_module` not to have its own binding.

Comment: Instead of plain `File`, would `const_get :File` do the trick?

Comment: Yes, but this question is all about syntax, i.e., whether it is possible to make my current syntax (where I just say `File`) work as desired.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is impossible to evaluate a token representing a constant (of which classes and modules are special case) later (within a different namespace). Constants are set the first time they are parsed, so if you have a token `File` to be parsed as a token, it will be evaluated as such at to moment of (and in the context of) parsing. The best you can do is pass something like `:File` or `"File"`, which are not parsed as a constant, and somehow have it later participate in the definition of a constant (for example, using `const_set`).

Comment: I can use `:File` and then resolve it myself to whatever I want.  I was curious if I could get away with using a nicer syntax.

Comment: Something else might be the problem. When the `File` token is parsed as a constant and is to be evaluated (at the very end), both `::File` and `M::File` constants exist. The result in this case is `::File`.  If I rewrote the same example in a "more standard way", without creating classes/modules dynamically and passing blocks around (`module M; class File; end; File end`) the result would be `M::File`. In the latter case there exists a lexical (enclosing) scope when `File` is being resolved, so the outcome is different.  My question is whether I can get the same behavior in the former case.